# Can't change UITableView frame in searchBar methods

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a view controller which is fully occupied by a UINavigationBar and UITableView. When the user taps the search bar in the UITableView, I want to hide the navigation bar and allow the table view to fully occupy the screen. Here's my code:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    NSLog(@"typing text");
    navBar.hidden = YES;
    [tableview setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 568)];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"clearing text");
    navBar.hidden = NO;
    [tableview setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 504)];
}
```

However, the appearance/frame change code is not working. On the other hand, I know these methods are being called because the NSLogs show up. Can anyone offer any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    NSLog(@"typing text");
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 568)];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"clearing text");
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 504)];
}
```

There is something about adding the animation flag that corrects the problem. Hope this helps!

Comment: The table view set frame is still not working when using this code.

Comment: Make sure your tableview is outlet is hooked up if you are using interface builder as I just tried it and it works for me. Let me know if that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use search display controller (UISearchDisplayController class) for the search functionality.

A search display controller manages display of a search bar and a table view that displays the results of a search of data. I believe it also comes with the functionality you are attempting to create above.

This guide is helpful: http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/

Comment: I am using a UISearchDisplayController. However, I'm not using a UINavigationController. As I said, the view controller just contains a UINavigationBar and a UITableView (which contains a search display controller).